# HTML agility pack is adding unnecessary string to the outer html

Tags: c#, dom, html-parsing, html-agility-pack, string-parsing

I am trying to remove class, style and such attributes from given tagged string

for example string is

```
<math>K_B \cap\left \{ |k| < \beta\right \} </math>
```

Once i load it to the HtmlDocument it becomes as below

```
<math>K_B \cap\left \{ |k| < \beta\right="" \}=""></math>
```

[image]

How can I prevent this behavior from happening? Because this behavior is breaking my code

My aim is for example if string is like below

```
<math style="gg" class="cg" >K_B \cap\left \{ |k| < \beta\right \} </math>
```

Turning it like below

```
<math>K_B \cap\left \{ |k| < \beta\right \} </math>
```

Comment: My guess would be the `<` character is confusing the parser..

Comment: @stuartd probably. so any ideas?

Comment: If the `<math>` elements doesn't contain any other child elements, replace occurrence of `<` with `&lt;` but only where they occur within the `math` element, with a regex maybe